# Friends & Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, opencl

I have the following code:

```
(*writeOutputToBuffer)(cl::EnqueueArgs(*queue, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(netSpec[lastLayerIndex]), cl::NullRange), writeOutputToBufferBuf[0], writeOutputToBufferBuf[1], lastLayerIndex);
```

where `writeOutputToBufferBuf[0]` contains a `cl::Buffer`,

`writeOutputToBufferBuf[1]` contains another `cl::Buffer`

and `lastLayerIndex` contains a `int`.

`writeOutputToBufferBuf` is a vector of `cl::Buffer`

Using the above code in its own class works perfectly fine. The call that was successful was this:

> (cl::make_kernel< cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, int >) (cl::EnqueueArgs, cl::Buffer&, cl::Buffer&, int&)

The kernel is initialized as:

```
 std::shared_ptr<cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, int>> writeOutputToBuffer;
```

but when I use them in a friend class as follows:

```
(fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBuffer)(cl::EnqueueArgs(*queue, cl::NullRange,
                        cl::NDRange(outputSize), cl::NullRange),  (fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBufferBuf[0]),
                            (fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBufferBuf[1]), (fullyConnectedPortion->lastLayerIndex));
```

it returns this error:

> no match for call to ‘(std::shared_ptr < cl::make_kernel< cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, int > >) (cl::EnqueueArgs, cl::Buffer&, cl::Buffer&, int&)’

How do I fix this issue?

---

I tried to make a more detailed example below, I hope it helps. The actual lines of codes are too long to post here and needs openCL to compile. I think its just supposed to be a issue with my use of pointers though.

```
class FCN{
public:

    std::vector<cl::Buffer> writeOutputToBufferBuf;
    friend class NeuralNetwork;

    void initialize();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, int>> writeOutputToBuffer;
}

class NN{
public:
    FCN* FCNN;

    void calc();
}

void FCN::initialize(){
//puts data into writeOutputToBufferBuf
}

void NN::calc(){

 (fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBuffer)(cl::EnqueueArgs(*queue, cl::NullRange,
                        cl::NDRange(outputSize), cl::NullRange),  (fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBufferBuf[0]),
                            (fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBufferBuf[1]), (fullyConnectedPortion->lastLayerIndex));

}

int main(){

 NN *nnnet = new NN;
 FCN *fcnet = new FCN;

 (*FCN).initialize();
 (*NN).calc();
}
```

Comment: `(fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBuffer)` should be `(fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBuffer[0])` maybe. But you'll need to provide a MCVE for anyone to really be able to help you.

Comment: Noted, I'll update the OP with a MCVE when I can.

It can't be `(fullyConnectedPortion->writeOutputToBuffer[0])` though, `writeOutputToBuffer` itself is not a vector, only `writeOutputToBufferBuf`.

Comment: You have `(*writeOutputToBuffer)` in the first example, so I would guess you'd need to dereference it in the second.

Comment: The first example's `(*writeOutputToBuffer)` is equivalent to `(this->writeOutputToBuffer)`, where the function is ran in the class which initializes `writeOutputToBuffer`.